# How to put Spring parameter value in jsp page as a jQgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

In spring controller there is a return type model and view. in that I am returning an JSON array to a view . Now I want to put that JSON array in the Jqgrid or editable datagrid structure using ajax.  can anyone help me or tell me how to do it.

This is my controller:-

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
    rel_details reldetails = (rel_details) command;
    List l=reldetailsdao.save_release_details(reldetails);

    JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    Iterator itr=l.iterator();
    rel_details asd=null;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        asd=(rel_details)itr.next();

        JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_id", asd.getRel_id());
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_name", asd.getRel_name());
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_modified_date", asd.getRel_modified_date());
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_desc", asd.getRel_desc());
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_env", asd.getRel_env());
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_change_req_no", asd.getRel_change_req_no());
          formDetailsJson.put("rel_status", asd.getRel_status());
          jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
    }

    responseDetailsJson.put("l", jsonArray);
    System.out.println(responseDetailsJson);


    return new ModelAndView("release","rel",responseDetailsJson);

}
```

This is the jsp:-

```
    <form:form action="release_view.htm" method="POST"
        commandName="rel_view_details" target="frame3">
        <c:if test="${fn:length(rel) > 0}">
            <table align="center" border=1px>
                <tr>
                    <th>Release ID</th>
                    <th>Release Name</th>
                    <th>Release Date</th>
                    <th>Release Description</th>
                    <th>Release Environment</th>
                    <th>Change Request No.</th>
                    <th>Work Status</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${rel}" var="rel" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="rel_id" id="rel_id"
                            value="${rel.rel_id}"><a
                            href="<c:url value="/view_change.htm?rel_id=${rel.rel_id}"/>"
                            target="frame3"> ${rel.rel_id}</a></td>
                        <td>${rel.rel_name}</td>
                        <fmt:formatDate value="${rel.rel_modified_date}" type="date"
                            pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" var="rel_modified_date" />
                        <td>${rel_modified_date}</td>
                        <td>${rel.rel_desc}</td>
                        <td>${rel.rel_env}</td>
                        <td>${rel.rel_change_req_no}</td>
                        <td>${rel.rel_status}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Modify/Delete" />
        </c:if>
    </form:form>

<div style="color: red;">${rel}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be much easier using the `@ResponseBody` annotation (more on the [spring blog](http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/))

Comment: if I use `@Responsebody` then how to return inside this function 
`protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)`

Comment: Oh, looks like you're using `SimpleFormController`; it's not clear how and why you're submitting all this through a form (and not AJAXing it) but it looks that you could find some interesting ideas in that "AJAX simplifications" blog post I linked before.